# Natural density of primes congruent to m modulo N and to r modulo S

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

N and S are two different primes. I would like to ask if primes, except N and S, congruent to m modulo N and to r modulo S, gcd(m,N)=gcd(r,S)=1, have natural density 1/φ(Ν)*1/φ(S).

Comment: That should only be true if you expect that being relatively prime to $N$ and relatively prime to $S$ are essentially independent events.  What condition on $N$ and $S$ do you need to make this a reasonable expectation?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited the question. N and S are two different primes.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general, consider e.g. $N=S$...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If N is not equal to S?